# Select a single document from Multiple Document Selector Kentico

Tags: kentico

I am using a Multiple Document Selector field on one of my document types, so the user can select many documents they like.

Now I would like to loop through each of those documents and apply some HTML tags, my current solution applies the same rule to all of those documents, what I need to be able to do is find the second document that has been selected on the multiple document selector and apply a different rule!

Does anyone know how I can find the second element or any single element from the multiple document selector control.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Multiple Document Selector is not a standard Kentico control so I don't know how the value is stored but I guess it's something like comma-separated list of NodeAliasPaths. E.g.:

```
/News/News-1, /Products/Phones, /Services
```

In that case you can use K# macro:

```
Documents["/Page"].MutipleDocumentField.Split(",")[0] 
// Selects the first document in MultipleDocumentField on page with NodeAliasPath == "/Page"
```

or

```
CMSContext.CurrentDocument.MutipleDocumentField.Split(",")[1] 
// Selects the second document in MultipleDocumentField on the current page
```

Macros can also use loops and have lots of [built-in methods](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Reference+-+Macro+methods). See the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Macro+syntax) or the following example:

```
{% foreach (x in Documents["/Home"].SubmitText.Split(",")) {"<a href=\""+ResolveUrl("~"+x)+"\">"+x+"</a>"} %}
```

In my case it generates the following HTML:

```
<a href="/8.1/CMS/Partners">/Partners</a>
<a href="/8.1/CMS/News">/News</a>
<a href="/8.1/CMS/Services">/Services</a>
```

You can use macros in all web part fields. Try inserting the code e.g. to static text web part.